# PyQt5. Ошибка при попытке считать текст из поля(line Edit) для сохранения

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Использую PyQt5. Имеется программа для обработки регулярного выражения и сохранения результатов в файл через проводник.

Есть 2 класса - основное окошко (class Window) и вспомогательное, менюшка сверху (class MenuDemo).

При нажатии на кнопку 'Save results' должен использоваться метод класса Window, для этого я создал экземпляр его класса внутри другого класса, но выбивает странную ошибку.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QAction, QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text = QLineEdit()
        self.label = QLabel('Input Regular expression')
        self.sav_btn = QPushButton('Save results')
        self.clr_btn = QPushButton('Clear text')
        self.combo_param_search = QComboBox()
        self.combo_ready_examples = QComboBox()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # main v_box
        v_box = QVBoxLayout()

        # box for down page
        h_box_down = QHBoxLayout()

        # box for up page
        h_box_up = QHBoxLayout()

        list_search = ['match', 'find all', 'sub']
        self.combo_param_search.addItems(list_search)

        list_examples = ['My regular', 'names', 'urls', 'mails']
        self.combo_ready_examples.addItems(list_examples)

        # box for normal label
        h_box_label = QHBoxLayout()
        h_box_label.addStretch()
        h_box_label.addWidget(self.label)
        h_box_label.addStretch()

        # must write two list into h_box_up

        # box for down page
        h_box_down.addWidget(self.clr_btn)
        h_box_down.addWidget(self.sav_btn)

        # box for up page
        h_box_up.addWidget(self.combo_param_search)
        h_box_up.addWidget(self.combo_ready_examples)

        # box for main page
        v_box.addLayout(h_box_label)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box_up)
        v_box.addWidget(self.text)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box_down)

        self.setLayout(v_box)

        self.clr_btn.clicked.connect(self.clear_text)
        self.sav_btn.clicked.connect(MenuDemo.save_file)

    def clear_text(self):
        self.text.clear()


class MenuDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.form_widget = Window()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        self.unit_ui()

    def unit_ui(self):
        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu('File')
        quit = bar.addMenu('Quit')

        open_action = QAction('Open', self)
        open_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')

        save_action = QAction('Save', self)
        save_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')

        file.addAction(open_action)
        file.addAction(save_action)

        quit.aboutToShow.connect(self.close)
        file.triggered.connect(self.respond)

        self.setWindowTitle("Find Regulars")

    def selected(self, q):
        print(q.text() + ' selected')

    def respond(self, q):
        signal = q.text()

        if signal == 'Open':
            self.open_file()
        elif signal == 'Save':
            self.save_file()

    def open_file(self):
        try:
            filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'))
            with open(filename[0], 'r') as f:
                file_text = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

    def save_file(self):
        try:
            filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, 'Save File', os.getenv('HOME'))
            with open(filename[0], 'w') as f:
                my_text = self.form_widget.text.text()
                f.write(my_text)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass


class Search:
    pass


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    menus = MenuDemo()
    menus.resize(400, 200)    
    menus.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Выбивает ошибку на моменте сохранения через кнопку `Save results`.

Текст ошибки:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'form_widget'

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том как вы callback передаёте:

```
    self.sav_btn.clicked.connect(MenuDemo.save_file) #XXX broken
```

`MenuDemo.save_file` это функция, а не привязанный метод. Поэтому `save_file` вместо `self` получает `False`  (`bool`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QPushButton('Press me')
w.clicked.connect(print)

# center on screen
w.adjustSize()  # update w.rect() now
w.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - w.rect().center())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вместо `MenuDemo.save_file` следует `menus.save_file` передать в `connect()` (можно callback как аргумент в Window передать).

Comment: Попробовал - menus он вообще не видит внутри класса Window, пошел другим путем, попробовал в __init__ создать экземпляр класса MenuDemo `self.from_Menu = MenuDemo()` и соответственно, вызвал его через это экземпляр `self.sav_btn.clicked.connect(self.from_Menu.save_file)`, но выбивает уже другую ошибку - ошибку максимального кол-ва вызова рекурсии

Comment: @helsereet: естественно не видит. Это ваш код или вы скопировали откуда-то? Вы понимаете как аргументы передавать в Питоне? Попробуйте: `Window(callback=self.save_file)` (как предложено в ответе) исправьте `def save_file()` и `Window.__init__` соответственно.